# Is this sentence from the Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung correct?

Tags: grammar-identification, possessive

The two [paragraphs](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/brexit/britischer-aussenminister-tusk-hat-britisches-volk-beleidigt-15801570.html) below come from today’s online edition of the *Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung* (emphasis mine):

> Im Streit um den Brexit liegen die Nerven blank: Der britische
>   Außenminister Jeremy Hunt beschuldigte am Samstag EU-Ratspräsident
>   Donald Tusk, mit einem Foto vom EU-Gipfel „das britische Volk
>   beleidigt“ zu haben. Hunt bezog sich auf ein von Tusk bei Instagram
>   gepostetes Bild, das die britische Premierministerin Theresa May mit
>   dem EU-Ratspräsidenten am Kuchenbüfett zeigt. Als Kommentar schrieb
>   Tusk: „Ein Stück Kuchen gefällig? Tut mir leid, keine Kirschen.“
>
> *Damit versuchte Tusk**s** offenbar eine humoristische Anspielung auf das
>   Großbritannien von EU-Seite oft vorgehaltene Rosinen-Picken bei den
>   Brexit-Verhandlungen – die englische Redewendung dafür lautet
>   „Kirschen-Picken“.* Die schwierigen Gespräche drehen sich um die
>   künftigen Beziehungen zwischen London und der Europäischen Union.

I know that the FAZ pays special attention to the correct usage of the German language in its articles. But after having read the first sentence of the second paragraph (in italics) many times, I still cannot understand **why**:

1. There is an *s* at the end of *Tusk* (the name of the President of the European Council is Donald Tusk). To me the presence of *s* seems to be a mistake.
2. It is written *auf das Großbritannien*. Should it not be *auf Großbritannien**s***? Then the sentence would read:

   > Damit versuchte Tusk offenbar eine humoristische Anspielung auf Großbritanniens von EU-Seite oft vorgehaltene Rosinen-Picken bei den Brexit-Verhandlungen...

Answer (score 9):

1) Ja, das ist ein Fehler der FAZ.

2) Nein, das ist richtig so. Großbritannien ist der Adressat der Vorhaltungen, und muss daher ein Dativobjekt sein.

Kürzen wir den Satz soweit es geht zurück:

> Damit versuchte Tusk offenbar eine humoristische Anspielung auf das
>   Großbritannien von EU-Seite oft vorgehaltene Rosinenpicken bei den
>   Brexitverhandlungen.

(Für die Bindestriche sehe ich keinen Anlass).

Noch ein wenig:

> Damit versuchte Tusk eine Anspielung auf das Großbritannien von EU-Seite vorgehaltene Rosinenpicken.

Man könnte den Satz auch umstellen:

> Damit versuchte Tusk eine Anspielung auf das von EU-Seite Großbritannien vorgehaltene Rosinenpicken.

oder

> Damit versuchte Tusk eine Anspielung auf das Rosinenpicken, das von EU-Seite Großbritannien vorgehalten wird.

Wie Jahnka richtig schreibt gehört das *das* zum Rosinenpicken.

Answer (score 3):

Und ein drittes Angebot, diesen Monstersatz zu entzerren:

Damit versuchte Tusk offenbar eine humoristische Anspielung auf das Rosinen-Picken, das [wem? -> Dativ] Großbritannien von EU-Seite oft vorgehalten wird.

As to your "I **know** that the FAZ pays special attention to the correct usage of the German language" - vielleicht solltest du da nicht so sicher sein, sondern in Betracht ziehen, dass das auch ein Mythos sein kann. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Sie haben Recht. Es sollte heißen

> Damit versuchte **Tusk** offenbar eine humoristische Anspielung auf **Großbritanniens** von EU-Seite oft vorgehaltene Rosinen-Picken bei den Brexit-Verhandlung ...

Verkürzt man den Satz bis aufs Wesentliche, bleibt

> Damit versuchte **Tusk** eine Anspielung auf **Großbritanniens** Rosinen-Picken.

Comment: Bei Nummer 2 ist auch die originale Formulierung korrekt, siehe Antwort von user unknown.